# Spring Data Neo4j 5 node/relationship labels and inheritance

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

I have the following Spring Data Neo4j 5 entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value extends Flaggable {

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

}
```

Right now the `Value` nodes have the following labels:

```
MATCH(n:Value) RETURN labels(n) LIMITS 1

["BaseEntity", "Subscribable", "Flaggable", "Likeable", "Value"]
```

In some cases, according to my project requirements I need to extend the `Value` node with additional properties, like for example `weight` and `size`.

I don't want to change the existing `Value` class and want to introduce a new - inherited one, for example:

```
@NodeEntity
public class WeightedValue extends Value{

    private Long weight;

    private Long size;

}
```

I have a question, will the following query `MATCH(n:Value) RETURN n` return also the instances of `WeightedValue` ?

Will it be possible to search `WeightedValue` nodes(by `Value` label) by the following query?

`MATCH(n:Value) WHERE n.size > 1000 RETURN n`

Will the approach above work for `@RelationshipEntity` and inheritance? So is it possible to use inheritance for `@RelationshipEntity` and how to keep the same label(for example `HAS_VALUE_ON`) for the base and inherited classes, for example:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_VALUE_ON")
public class RelationshipValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Decision decision;

    @EndNode
    private Characteristic characteristic;

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_VALUE_ON")
public class WeightedRelationshipValue extends RelationshipValue {

    private Long weight;

    private Long size; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, nodes created by `WeightedValue extends Value` class would have both the `Value` and `WeightedValue` labels (you can make it so it doesn't have the super class if you wanted).  So, as long as ALL `WeightedValue` nodes are `Value` nodes, then you can `MATCH` on `Value` nodes.

Also, in your question you ask if a Cypher `MATCH` query will work, but I wanted to ensure you weren't assuming the behind-the-scenes query that SDN might turn your repository query in to  (i.e. findAll()).  I am not certain, at all, but it is possible that SDN might convert something such as `weightedValueRepo.findAll()` into something like: `MATCH (n:Value:WeightedValue) return n;`  In Cypher this returns the node thus all it's properties.  However, if in Java you used `List<Value> values = valueRepo.findAll()` keep in mind that a Value object may not have all the same Java/class properties as `WeightedValue` objects.

So, in Cypher matching/querying on the Value label can get you access to the entire node (including properties defined only in WeightedValue objects, finding/matching via SDN may not because the OGM has to map the properties of a node to a class (and that super class doesn't generally have the same properties as it's subclasses).

For the second part, a single `Relationship`, I believe, has only a single type and does not work like labels, where an entity can have multiple.  You can create multiple relationships of different types between the same nodes, though.  I am uncertain if one `@RelationshipEntity` extends another if SDN would create both rels or not.  Maybe you can try it and let me know. :slightly_smiling_face: